# Can not update content of one RealmSwift.List with another

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

Have classes Setting, Device and Attributes:

```
class SettingType: CustomStringConvertible {
    let key: Attributes.Keys

    init(key: Attributes.Keys) {
        self.key = key
    }

    var name: String? {
        return self.key.description
    }

    var description: String {
        return "no value in SettingsType"
    }
}

class Setting<T>: SettingType {
    var value: T

    init(key: Attributes.Keys, value: T) {
        self.value = value
        super.init(key: key)
    }

    override var description: String {
        guard let descriptible = value as? CustomStringConvertible else {
            return "value has not description"
        }
        return descriptible.description
    }
}

class Device: Object, Mappable, Extensible {
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    var id = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var attributes: Attributes!
    dynamic var name: String!
    dynamic var phone: String!
    dynamic var uniqueId: String!
    dynamic var category: String?
    dynamic var contact: String?
    let geofenceIds = RealmSwift.List<Integer>()
    let groupId = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var lastUpdate: String?
    dynamic var model: String?
    let positionId = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var status: String?
    dynamic var photo: Data?

    convenience init(id: Int? = nil, attributes: Attributes = Attributes.empty, name: String, phone: String, uniqueId: String) {
        self.init()
        self.id.value = id
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.uniqueId = uniqueId
    }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id.value            <- map["id"]
        attributes          <- map["attributes"]
        name                <- map["name"]
        phone               <- map["phone"]
        uniqueId            <- map["uniqueId"]
        category            <- map["category"]
        contact             <- map["contact"]
        geofenceIds         <- map["geofenceIds"]
        groupId.value       <- map["groupId"]
        lastUpdate          <- map["lastUpdate"]
        model               <- map["model"]
        positionId.value    <- map["positionId"]
        status              <- map["status"]
    }
}

extension Device {
    var settings: [SettingType] {
        get {
            var result = [SettingType]()
            for key in Attributes.Keys.settings {
                switch key {
                case .showOnMap         :
                    result.append(Setting<Bool>(key: key, value: self.attributes.showOnMap))
                case .observers         :
                    result.append(Setting<RealmSwift.List<Observer>>(key: key, value: self.attributes.listObservers))
                case .trackingMode      :
                    guard let trackMode = self.attributes.trackingMode else {
                        result.append(Setting<TrackMode>.defaultValue(for: key)!)
                        break
                    }
                    result.append(Setting<TrackMode>(key: key, value: trackMode))
                case .timeZone          :
                    guard
                        let rawTimeZone = self.attributes.rawTimeZone,
                        let timeZone = TimeZone(rawValue: rawTimeZone)
                        else {
                            result.append(Setting<TimeZone>.defaultValue(for: key)!)
                            break
                    }
                    result.append(Setting<TimeZone>(key: key, value: timeZone))
                case .language          :
                    guard let language = self.attributes.language else {
                        result.append(Setting<Language>.defaultValue(for: key)!)
                        break
                    }
                    result.append(Setting<Language>(key: key, value: language))
                case .sosContacts       :
                    result.append(Setting<RealmSwift.List<Contact>>(key: key, value: self.attributes.listSosContacts))
                case .favoriteContacts  :
                    result.append(Setting<RealmSwift.List<Contact>>(key: key, value: self.attributes.listFavoriteContacts))
                case .alarms            :
                    result.append(Setting<RealmSwift.List<Alarm>>(key: key, value: self.attributes.listAlarms))
                case .silentMode        :
                    result.append(Setting<RealmSwift.List<SilentInterval>>(key: key, value: self.attributes.listSilentMode))
                case .pedometer         :
                    result.append(Setting<Bool>(key: key, value: self.attributes.pedometer))
                case .watchBattery      :
                    result.append(Setting<Bool>(key: key, value: self.attributes.watchBattery))
                case .notifyOnRemoval   :
                    result.append(Setting<Bool>(key: key, value: self.attributes.notifyOnRemoval))
                case .settingModel      :
                    guard let model = self.model else {
                        result.append(Setting<String>.defaultValue(for: key)!)
                        break
                    }
                    result.append(Setting<String>(key: key, value: model))
                case .settingPhone      :
                    guard let phone = self.phone else {
                        result.append(Setting<String>.defaultValue(for: key)!)
                        break
                    }
                    result.append(Setting<String>(key: key, value: phone))
                case .settingUniqueId   :
                    guard let uniqueId = self.uniqueId else {
                        result.append(Setting<String>.defaultValue(for: key)!)
                        break
                    }
                    result.append(Setting<String>(key: key, value: uniqueId))
                case .settingName       :
                    guard let name = self.name else {
                        result.append(Setting<String>.defaultValue(for: key)!)
                        break
                    }
                    result.append(Setting<String>(key: key, value: name))
                default                 :   break
                }
            }
            return result
        }
        set {
            for setting in newValue {
                switch setting.key {
                case .showOnMap         :   self.attributes.showOnMap = (setting as! Setting<Bool>).value

                case .observers         :
                    self.attributes.listObservers.removeAll()
                    self.attributes.listObservers.append(objectsIn: (setting as! Setting<RealmSwift.List<Observer>>).value)

                case .sosContacts       :
                    self.attributes.listSosContacts.removeAll()
                    self.attributes.listSosContacts.append(objectsIn: (setting as! Setting<RealmSwift.List<Contact>>).value)

                case .favoriteContacts  :
                    self.attributes.listFavoriteContacts.removeAll()
                    self.attributes.listFavoriteContacts.append(objectsIn: (setting as! Setting<RealmSwift.List<Contact>>).value)

                case .alarms            :
                    self.attributes.listAlarms.removeAll()
                    self.attributes.listAlarms.append(objectsIn: (setting as! Setting<RealmSwift.List<Alarm>>).value)

                case .silentMode        :
                    self.attributes.listSilentMode.removeAll()
                    self.attributes.listSilentMode.append(objectsIn: (setting as! Setting<RealmSwift.List<SilentInterval>>).value)

                case .trackingMode      :   self.attributes.trackingMode = (setting as! Setting<TrackMode>).value
                case .timeZone          :   self.attributes.rawTimeZone = (setting as! Setting<TimeZone>).value.rawValue
                case .language          :   self.attributes.language = (setting as! Setting<Language>).value
                case .pedometer         :   self.attributes.pedometer = (setting as! Setting<Bool>).value
                case .watchBattery      :   self.attributes.watchBattery = (setting as! Setting<Bool>).value
                case .notifyOnRemoval   :   self.attributes.notifyOnRemoval = (setting as! Setting<Bool>).value
                case .settingModel      :   self.model = (setting as! Setting<String>).value
                case .settingPhone      :   self.phone = (setting as! Setting<String>).value
                case .settingUniqueId   :   self.uniqueId = (setting as! Setting<String>).value
                case .settingName       :   self.name = (setting as! Setting<String>).value
                default                 :   break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Attributes: Object, Mappable {
    static let empty = Attributes()

    enum Keys: String {
        case showOnMap
        case observers
        case trackingMode
        case timeZone
        case language
        case sosContacts
        case favoriteContacts
        case alarms
        case silentMode
        case pedometer
        case watchBattery
        case notifyOnRemoval
        case settingModel
        case settingPhone
        case settingUniqueId
        case settingName
        case emptySetting

        case modified

        case sat
        case rssi
        case battery
        case steps
        case ip
        case distance
        case totalDistance

        static let settings: [Keys] = [.showOnMap, .observers, .trackingMode, .timeZone, .language, .sosContacts, .favoriteContacts, .alarms, .silentMode, .pedometer, .watchBattery, .notifyOnRemoval, .settingModel, .settingPhone, .settingUniqueId, .settingName]

    let sat = RealmOptional<Int>()
    let rssi = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var battery: String?
    let steps = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var ip: String?
    let distance = RealmOptional<Double>()
    let totalDistance = RealmOptional<Double>()

    dynamic var showOnMap = false

    dynamic var rawTrackingMode: String?
    var trackingMode: TrackMode? {
        set {
            guard
                let newValue = newValue
                else {
                    self.rawTrackingMode = nil
                    return
            }
            self.rawTrackingMode = newValue.rawValue
        }
        get {
            guard
                let rawTrackingMode = self.rawTrackingMode,
                let trackMode = TrackMode(rawValue: rawTrackingMode)
                else {
                    return nil
            }
            return trackMode
        }
    }

    dynamic var rawTimeZone: String?

    dynamic var rawLanguage: String?
    var language: Language? {
        set {
            guard let newValue = newValue else {
                self.rawLanguage = nil
                return
            }
            self.rawLanguage = newValue.rawValue
        }
        get {
            guard
                let rawLanguage = self.rawLanguage,
                let language = Language(rawValue: rawLanguage)
                else {
                    return nil
            }
            return language
        }
    }

    let listObservers = RealmSwift.List<Observer>()
    let listSosContacts = RealmSwift.List<Contact>()
    let listFavoriteContacts = RealmSwift.List<Contact>()
    let listAlarms = RealmSwift.List<Alarm>()
    let listSilentMode = RealmSwift.List<SilentInterval>()

    dynamic var pedometer = false
    dynamic var watchBattery = false
    dynamic var notifyOnRemoval = false

    dynamic var modified: String?

    dynamic var alarm: String?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        sat.value           <- map[Keys.sat.rawValue]
        rssi.value          <- map[Keys.rssi.rawValue]
        battery             <- map[Keys.battery.rawValue]
        steps.value         <- map[Keys.steps.rawValue]
        ip                  <- map[Keys.ip.rawValue]
        distance.value      <- map[Keys.distance.rawValue]
        totalDistance.value <- map[Keys.totalDistance.rawValue]
        showOnMap           <- map[Keys.showOnMap.rawValue]

        listObservers           <- map[Keys.observers.rawValue]
        listAlarms              <- map[Keys.alarms.rawValue]
        listSosContacts         <- map[Keys.sosContacts.rawValue]
        listFavoriteContacts    <- map[Keys.favoriteContacts.rawValue]
        listSilentMode          <- map[Keys.silentMode.rawValue]

        trackingMode        <- (map[Keys.trackingMode.rawValue], EnumTransform<TrackMode>())
        rawTimeZone         <- map[Keys.timeZone.rawValue]
        language            <- (map[Keys.language.rawValue], EnumTransform<Language>())
        pedometer           <- map[Keys.pedometer.rawValue]
        watchBattery        <- map[Keys.watchBattery.rawValue]
        notifyOnRemoval     <- map[Keys.notifyOnRemoval.rawValue]
        modified            <- map[Keys.modified.rawValue]
        alarm               <- map["alarm"]
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I try update attributes of device using "Settings interface":

```
func updateSettings(of device: Device, settings: [SettingType], handler: ((Device) -> Void)? = nil) {
    do {
        try RealmManager.shared.realm.write {
            device.settings = settings
        }
        handler?(device)
    } catch {
        self.fail(with: error)
    }
}
```

lists in attributes of device updates incorrectly, I will lose data of unchanged lists. May be problem is lists holds also Realm managed objects (Observer, Alarm, Contact, SilentInterval) but they have not primary keys?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:** Found "bug", when I'm removing all objects from "old" List, it also removing all objects from "new" one... But why? And how get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since classes are `reference types`, when you write `let newList = oldList`, where `oldList` is a `Realm List`, you don't copy the contents of the list, you just copy a reference. This means that both `newList` and `oldList` will be pointing to the same objects in memory and hence if you modify one of them, both will be modified.

To copy all values of `oldList` into `newList`, you can create new unmanaged copies of the objects in `oldList` and store them in `newList` by using

`let newList = oldList.map{Setting(value:$0)}`

This way the changes you apply to one of your lists won't be reflected on the other list.

Comment: Thanks, found out it already, but thanks anyway! Found out that Realm is not an option for my project btw

Comment: No worries. Realm is a great framework, but of course it isn't the right way to go for each and every project. Hope you'll find an alternative more suitable for your project.